# Questions about Arbor.js visualisation too

Tags: javascript, visualization, arbor.js

I am researching on data visualization tools and need the answers for the following questions about Arbor.js.

Is arbor.js Open Source or not?
Type of input files that can be handled by arbor.js.
How easy is it for the developer to develop visualisations using tool?
Can it be used in other devices?
Availability of different functionalities like Drill down?
Integration with other softwares like R, SAS?
How easy or difficult is it to update data?
How well does it work with Big Data?

Thanks a lot

regards,
Leona

Comment: Arbor is released under the MIT license.

Comment: Thanks martin. Do you have the answers to the other questions as well?

Comment: Not really, otherwise i would have posted an answer. Really good starting point is http://arborjs.org/introduction also check out demos on github repo https://github.com/samizdatco/arbor/tree/master/demos